# How do C#/.NET assembly references get disconnected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependencies, .net-assembly

[Is this possibly an ORM thing? A Dapper Thing? Or a general .NET Framework thing?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTt6P.png)

Preface this by saying: I come from open source, more modern languages like Ruby and Javascript. I recently started a job where for the first time I am developing back on Windows, using Visual Studio IDE, and getting used to compiled vs interpreted code. If this is a dumb question I'm sorry, but google has come up very empty.

I've gotten TONS of results on how to deal with assembly issues and references, that basically get straight to the point and tell you how to reconnect them. What I want to know is this:

WHY would they get connected in the first place? How, and where does that happen? I can't imagine as a developer having a need to manipulate them or change the filepath. What is the causation?

Any help much appreciated. I'm going nuts here wondering!

Comment: C# is newer than Ruby and JS. Also, [check this post out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628798/what-is-in-a-dll-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is in a DLL and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628798/what-is-in-a-dll-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: For very slightly more information you can right click on the reference and go to "properties" and look at the file path; if it's in visual studio "packages" directory then I think that means it was added using something like nuget. If you right click and go to "add reference" and point to a DLL then the file path will be at the dll not the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHY would they get connected in the first place?
```

Those references are dependencies that the program needs. They work similarly as having different `JavaScript` libraries in your front-end web project.

```
How, and where does that happen?
```

The `.csproj` file is an `.xml` file that is keeping track of all that information plus how the application will be compiled. The linking occurs on compile time. Everything will exist in the `/bin` folder for you as a `.dll`.

```
I can't imagine as a developer having a need to manipulate them or change the filepath. What is the causation?
```

You should not be manipulating these on the fly normally. Everything should exist under the `/bin` folder

As I pointed out in the comments, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628798/what-is-in-a-dll-and-how-does-it-work). They are talking about a type of references.

Comment: Context for this question is I haven't changed them, and as you suggest there is not a lot of likelihood someone else is monkeying around with them if I read you correctly, but I'm running into the need to re-add them. The crux of the issue  is without me having adjusted the references, what precipitates needing to re-add them?

Comment: That seems to be a very specific problem. Why do you need to re add them? what is removing those references so you need to do this?

Comment: That is the crux of my question. As in, I know I didn't mess with them, and I can't think of any conceivable reason someone else may have. So how is  it that it results in a state where they are disconnected?

Answer (score 0):

Loading happens when code require specified DLL code.
Why to specify DLL path ? 
E.g. juggle DLL versions / clean memmory in the process
Unloading is possible but not recomended.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jasonz/2004/05/31/why-isnt-there-an-assembly-unload-method/