# html content/file displayed from browser not existent in webserver directory

Tags: c#, blazor, web-development-server

i got assigned to a project regarding webdevelopment, which i have very little experience in and am currently trying to understand the structure of the webpage. Right now I can't understand where some of the html code/files are located on the webservers directory. Looking into it from the browser and using webdeveloper tools on a certain page I can see that its named "register.cs" and placed in a certain folder. Looking into the webservers directory I can't find anything related to it not even by searching the whole folder. Does someone understand? The website was apparently coded in C# using blazor ´.

Comment: In your project directory (in server) there should be *.dll files that contains project code 
 (classes, interfaces etc) including mentioned file - register.cs.  You can read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628798/what-is-in-a-dll-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Ok I get it, but I still can't see it when i open the project inside visual studio 2019. Shouldnt the class be there somewhere outside of dll file?